# Operating System not found when OS is installed

Tags: windows-7, operating-systems

I've got something strange going on here. I have a a laptop which could reboot because the BIOS was set to start-up from network. I changed the booting order to the internal HD to be the first, but for some reason, the laptop still wouldn't boot.

So I took out the hard drive, installed in into an other laptop and installed a fresh copy of Windows 7 onto the hard drive. Everything went well and I've got a working copy of Windows 7 installed on the hard drive of the first laptop.
But, when I switched hard drives again (the hard drive with the fresh Windows 7 goes back into the broken laptop), I get the message "Operating System not found...", even though the hard drive does work without any issue in an other laptop...
Even when I insert the Windows Disk and tell the BIOS only to run from the DVD-Drive, I get the "Operating System not found" error...

What could be the cause of this strange behavior? And how can I solve this?
Is it possible the laptop hardware doesn't support Windows 7 and by so giving this error message?

Comment: It's more likely that the hard drive isn't being detected by the laptop.

Comment: That's what I thought. But the BIOS is detecting the hard drive (I guess). How does this come and how can I solve this? Or is this a motherboard failure?

Comment: Very hard to say from this side of the screen. Perhaps a local tech shop will be able to diagnose it for you.

Comment: I understand... Is there anything I can provide you with so you get a better view on the situation?

Comment: Nope. I think it's a physical problem, so I'd want to play with it to get an idea. Sorry :-(

Comment: for your error this may be reasons :Master Boot Record (MBR) on hard drive is broken. Note that some third-party programs or disk operations can damage an MBR.,An incompatible partition is marked as Active.A partition that contains the MBR is no longer active.cehck this issues

Comment: @vignesh, thanks for the comment. I've formatted the drive with the Windows 7 set-up tool, so I would think it's all ok, no? There are two partitions on the drive, so maybe there is the issue?

Comment: The two partitions are a Recovery Partition (13GB) and another partition (220GB)... Has it to do with this recovery partition?